# MongoDB not returning propper data to client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, mongodb, socket.io

When i attempt to send back the highscore database to the clients browser I just get the string "[Object Object], [Object Object], ..." and so on until the database ends.

The odd thing is this is only if i return it as an innerHTML, because when i return it via console.log() it prints out the correct data. Does anyone know why this is the case?

server.js

```
    socket.on('hsGo', function() {

        db.collection('dat').find({}, {projection: {_id: 0}})
        .sort({highscore : -1})
        .limit(10).toArray()
        .then(function (doc) {

            io.to(socket.id).emit('topPlayers', doc);

        });

    });
```

client.js

```
    socket.on('topPlayers', function(doc) {

        console.log(doc); 
        //Prints practically the correct data ^^^

        document.getElementById('yourscore').innerHTML = doc; 
        //prints [object object] ^^^

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I'll post the answer in case this helps anyone in the future.

Due to mongoDB returning an array, if i just send the string via innerHTML it will return an object, since i am printing the array. the following code on the client side fixed it.

```
document.getElementById('yourscore').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(doc);
```